# What make of frame

Tags: frames, identify-this-bike

Could you tell me what company makes this frame please,it's all alloy with the letter M moulded into it behind the saddle stem shaft but no other markings[image].[image: t]

Comment: Interesting frame - it does not have provisions for a rear disk brake, but seems to have some odd bosses for rim brakes.   The chainstay cutout suggests its a fatbike frame, but there's a cable stop for a front deraileur, which many fatbikes omit for clearance reasons.  So its quite an odd combination.

Comment: Looks like maybe a trials frame?  No seatpost clamp as well, indicating a locked on seat (with expander through the seat)?

Comment: I'd agree with some sort of trials frame as the brake bosses are 4-bolt as used for Magura hydraulic rim brakes and they were very popular for trials bikes. Chain-stay shape would mean you could run big fat trials tyres. 

Could be a Monty? But that's just a guess based on trials bike and Monty starts with an M.

Answer (score 6):

Thanks to DecSims comments to the original post I think I'm close.

Here's the logo
[image]

It is a [Monty trial bike](https://www.pinkbike.com/buysell/452495/).
The bike pictured is a Monty B221 X-Lite Mod.

My best guess is that it's a 2002 Monty 231 x-lite
[Link to the picture](https://stolen-bikes.co.uk/stolen-bikes/monty-231-x-lite/)
[image]

[Bicycle Blue Book](https://www.bicyclebluebook.com/value-guide/product/37591/)

Comment: Thank you DecSims,the picture of the blue Monty is identical to the frame,also the M is the same style as the Monty logo,much appreciate you information.
Ron.